# How to modify iptables rules via editing a file rather than interacting via command line?

Tags: centos, iptables

In the history, i would simply edit a file and then 
reboot the whole server.

i would clone the line that had port 22 open 
change it to 80 and then save the file.. and reboot 
the whole system so the iptables would start with port 80 open.

but in the recent times.. that file is no longer in existent 
in my centos 6.5 O.S.

most answers on google suggest i must interact with iptables 
in order to enable and disable ports.

is it possible to not interact with iptables but rather 
just see everything infront of you as one editable file ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In CentOS you have the file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` if you don't have it there, you can create it simply by using `iptables-save` to dump the current rule set into a file.

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

To load the file you don't need to restart the machine, you can use `iptables-restore`

```
iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Comment: This works as File creation and restauration, but after a reboot everything get back to the initial state! I am trying to add a script which is runnable on startup to apply this, but with no hope!

Comment: `iptables-restore` is good for OS start scripts. If you are doing some changes and want them to apply manually from console, there is a safer command `iptables-apply` - after a timeout it reverts all changes back if you accidentally cut yourself out of your server.

Comment: `iptables-apply` apparently isn't part of RedHat Enterprise 7.4 :-/

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be,
"service iptables save" to save it on /etc/sysconfig/iptables
then, "service iptables restart" to make sure that the rules created stays